# the R function summary puts a "1" in front of variables when its input is the output of an aovp function

Tags: r, anova

I am running a permutation test for a factorial ANOVA design. The output I get seems fine, but the summary function places a "1" in front of each variable. Here's my code:

```
summary(aovp(`Mean time in roi(s)` ~ Roi + Age + Sex, data = df))
```

Here is my output

```
[1] "Settings:  unique SS : numeric variables centered"
Component 1 :
            Df R Sum Sq R Mean Sq Iter Pr(Prob)    
Roi1         2   22.870   11.4349 5000   0.0206 *  
Age1         2   37.128   18.5641 5000   0.0004 ***
Sex1         1    0.004    0.0037   51   0.8824    
Residuals   72  211.118    2.9322
```

How can I get rid of those "1"s? Do they indicate a problem?

Additional Info:
The Roi and Age factors each have three levels. Roi is a fixed factor. Age is a random factor. Sex has two levels. It is a random factor.

Thank you!

Comment: That `1` is a factor level - the only way to calculate a statistic is by comparison between levels of the factor. E.g., compare what you see to `summary(lm(num ~ fac, data=data.frame(num=1:100, fac=factor(rep(c("F","M"), 50)))))` from a basic linear model with `F` and `M` as the factor levels.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I looked at my data again and saw that the class for Roi, Age, and Sex were "character" rather than "factor." I changed the class of those variables to "factor" and got the output I wanted. Thank you! Here's the code I used: 

```
df$Age <- as.factor(df$Age)
df$Roi <- as.factor(df$Roi)
df$Sex <- as.factor(df$Sex)
```